Who is the latest person to have obtain enlightenment and become a Buddha?
A number of people have become enlightened since Shakyamuni Buddha's realization of the truths. I'm curious as to who the latest person to have obtain enlightenment and become a Buddha is (as considered by the consensus of Buddhists)?

One answer might be:

The most recent Buddha was Gautama i.e. Siddhartha
The next will be Maitreya
Other people have become enlightened but were not "a Buddha"
There are different "levels" of enlightenment

Two of the characteristics of "a Buddha" include:

Teaches others (not "a private Buddha")
Rediscovers enlightenment from scratch i.e. after the previous Buddha's doctrine was lost to time and forgotten

Currently we're still within the Śāsana, so I guess by definition there won't be (perhaps needn't be) another.
Perhaps this isn't the doctrine of all Buddhists, but assuming it's the doctrine of at least some Buddhists, so there can be no "consensus" that there has been another.

The most recent claims to Full Enlightenment I read were by a married American doctor punk rocker Buddhist musician named Daniel Ingram. Daniel Ingram describes his life, at this link. Video: The Arahant - Daniel Ingram
